# How to clear values in ngx-bootstrap date picker?

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker

Currently it is accepting last selected values.

You can click [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/2.0.0-beta.8/#/datepicker) for a demo.

Comment: clear values  ??

Comment: The values I have selected in datepicker. please check link

Comment: Have a model and clear it using normal js like setting it to null and this will be reflected

Comment: Tried. It clear values of field but not clearing the selected dates.

Comment: can you reproduce this ? in stackblitz

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/2.0.0-beta.8/#/datepicker
check the demo in this link.

Answer (score 4):

If the component is designed right, you could just do the following programmatically.

```
this.bsValue = '';
```

From their doc, I don't see how to clear from UI other than your own methods.

Comment: What is bsvalue here. ?

Comment: If `bsValue` is referring to the `bsValue` property of the datepicker itself than it is not of type `string` but of type `Date`. Setting `bsValue` to `null` does indeed work.